# Create PostgreSQL 13 extension pldbgapi in Windows 10, to install debugger

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to Create the Extension pldbgapi for use with the Debugger.  I get the following error: SQL Error [58P01]: ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/pldbgapi.control": No such file or directory.

I happened to find that script in two places on my Windows 10 box:
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\share\extension  and
C:\Users\rjm\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\13\extension

The problem I am having is trying to get the Create Extension to look in either of the two windows folders! I am pretty new to Postgres so any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks!